# Solution to 99 lisp problems: P08 with functional javascript

Tags: javascript, lisp, functional-programming

## Solution to 99 lisp problems: P08, with functional javascript

> If a list contains repeated elements they should be replaced with a single copy of the element. The order of the elements should not be changed.

```
* (compress '(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e))
  (A B C A D E)
```

Anyone want to review?

```
function cond( check, _then, _continuation ) {
  if(check) return _then( _continuation )
  else return _continuation()
}

function compress( list ) {
  return (function check( index, item, nextItem, compressed ) {
    return cond( item !== nextItem, function _then( continuation ) {
        compressed = compressed.concat([ item ])
        return continuation()
      },
    function _continueation() {
      return cond(!nextItem, function _then() {
          return compressed
      }, 
      function _continuation() {
          return check( index + 1, list[index + 1], list[index + 2], compressed )  
      })
    })
  })( 0, list[0], list[1], [] )
}
```

ref: 
http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html

Comment: Wouldn't a loop or recursive calling be a better idea?

Comment: The `cond` function can probably be replaced with a ternary operator and switching the order a little.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need so much complexity in javascript. It's not a fully functional language, don't try to make it so.

```
var arr = [
    'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'e'
];

arr = arr.filter( function( el, i ) {
    // return if the current isn't the same as the next
    return el !== arr[ i + 1 ];
});

console.log( arr ); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "e"]
```

This is 2 lines.

Comment: The function passed to `filter` can be generalized by adding a third parameter `arr`.